# PhD for open data in Europe

Tags: research, education, europe

I am looking for a PhD in Europe related with open data. Do you know any university that works with this sector?

Comment: using it, or distributing it?  Using it would be just about any type of computing or science, particularly 'data scientists' ... distributing it is starting to come up via 'e-science' and 'data librarians'.

Answer (score 3):

The [Open University](http://www.open.ac.uk) and the [University of Southampton](http://www.southampton.ac.uk) definitely have their hands in open data. For more concrete ideas you'd have to look at the appropriate department (e.g. Computer Science) and find a supervisor.

Answer (score 2):

The Data and Web Science Group at the [University of Mannheim](https://www.uni-mannheim.de/dws/research/focus-groups/web-based-systems-prof-bizer/) does a lot of work with open data.

Answer (score 1):

I found a portal that lists PhD topics, coincidentally called "find a phd"

https://www.findaphd.com/phds/?Keywords=%22open+data%22

returns these 3 PhD programs (2019-03-12):

- University of East Anglia, School of Environmental Sciences
- University of Bath, Centre for Accountable, Responsible and Transparent AI
- Northumbria University, Faculty of Business and Law

By tweaking the search, for example "Linked Data", you might find others